# override the fullscreen tap or hide the fullscreen button -MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

When using the `MPMoviePlayerController` I want to override fullscreen button tap or to hide it so I can add a custom button.

The mission is to really change the `MPMoviePlayerController` frame and other subviews frame.

Any ideas? Or I must use different video player to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove gestures of your `MPMoviePlayerController`. Then add your custom gestures or Button or other control.

```
self.player.view.gestureRecognizers = nil; 
//Add your custom gestures or Button or other control
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently was solving similar issue. My client was insisting to disable Previous and Next buttons although I was strongly recommend to do that because it's quite tricky and not guaranteed to work in next iOS version. So here I publish my solution as an very unwanted option)

```
-(void) disableNextPrevButtons:(UIView *) view :(int) level {
    Class cl = NSClassFromString(@"MPKnockoutButton");
    for (UIView * v in view.subviews) {
        NSLog(@"[%d] scanning view of class %@ tag: %ld", level, NSStringFromClass(v.class), (long)v.tag);
        if ([v isKindOfClass:cl]) {
            for (UIView * v2 in v.subviews)
                if ([v2 isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                    v.alpha = 0.0;
                    v.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                    if (!buttonsDiscovered) {
                        buttonsDiscovered = YES;
                        UIButton * b  = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, v.superview.frame.size.height, v.superview.frame.size.height)];

                        if (MLGSystemVersion() > 7.9)
                            b.alpha = 0.5;
                        b.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   |
                                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  |
                                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    |
                                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
                        [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnMPPause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnMPPlay.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                        b.selected = YES;
                        [b addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPlayPauseDidPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                        b.center = CGPointMake(v.superview.frame.size.width / 2, v.center.y);
                        [v.superview addSubview:b];
                        self.btnPlayPause = b;
                    }

                    break;
                }
        } else
            [self disableNextPrevButtons:v :level +1];
    }
}
```

The method is recursevely scans and finds the desired controls and do some bad things to them